# Django Filter icontains count slow on TextField()

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-forms, django-templates

```
response_title = models.TextField(null=True,blank=True)
response_status_code = models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
response_body = models.TextField(null=True,blank=True)
```

recently I have been facing a slow performance for my site so Here's my observation from Django shell, I have 32k entries in my model & performing with `icontains` is slow compared to `contains` also `count` on `icontains` query took 4 seconds whereas `count` on `contain` took 0.3 seconds.

type of data I'm storing in `response_body` is Raw response body.

```
from .models import Response_Dataset

>>> Response_Dataset.objects.count() ## 0.1 sec
32289

>> Response_Dataset.objects.filter(response_body__icontains='hack') ## 0.4 seconds

>>> x = Response_Dataset.objects.filter(response_body__icontains='hack')
>>> x.count() ### 4 seconds
65

>>> x = Response_Dataset.objects.filter(response_body__contains='a') ### 0.2 seconds
>>> x.count() ### 0.3 seconds
23857
```

Performing with `icontains` on any other field beside the `response_body` is extremely fast such as on `response_title` or `response_status_code`

Comment: With regards to your last statement, doesn't `response_body` have a lot more text, and so it would naturally be slower to do a text match lookup?

Comment: Yes indeed `response_body`  would be larger compared to `response_title` but i don't think it should take time in seconds on  count()

Comment: It will. The number of rows in your table and the *content size* of  `response_body` plays the key role here.

Comment: What do you suggest me to go with for faster lookups in large content size rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to know when the Django Queryset actually gets its results from the database. Django ORM does not access the database until you actually need the value. It is described in detail in the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated).

   > Internally, a QuerySet can be constructed, filtered, sliced, and generally passed around without actually hitting the database. No database activity actually occurs until you do something to evaluate the queryset.

```py
from .models import Response_Dataset

>>> Response_Dataset.objects.count()  # ==> Database Hit
32289

>>> x = Response_Dataset.objects.filter(response_body__icontains='hack') # ==> Doesn't hit
>>> x.count() # ==> Hit
65

>>> x = Response_Dataset.objects.filter(response_body__contains='a') # ==> Doesn't hit
>>> x.count() # ==> Hit
23857
```

2. If certain SQL statements are slow, it is necessary to look at the `EXPLAIN SELECT` statements in the database and set the Index appropriately. You can install the Django Debug Toolbar and use the [debugsqlshell command](https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/commands.html#debugsqlshell) to view the SQL requested by the database. The method of optimization depends on the DBMS you are using.
3. In my opinion, if you want to do a full text search on a really large data set, a search engine like ElasticSearch is the right choice.

Comment: I was thinking to go with  FTS , I think Postgres has inbuilt support with  `vectorfield` but I'm really not sure how much space it would take more.

Comment: If the database is in a cloud environment, I think that the most accurate benchmark would be to restore to a backup of the database for a while to see how much space has changed since the ALTER TABLE. It is highly recommended that you be careful not to connect to your production environment when benchmarking. It's easy to make mistakes when creating new connection information. Good luck :)